# Redis eval command vs transaction command

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

In my last project, I used Redis as a cache DB. I should use Redis atomic operation so I use `EVAL` command and run Lua script.

Redis also contain Transaction command. Can you explain to me what's the difference between transaction and `EVAL` command?

When should I use each one?

Thanks

Comment: Read [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval) and [Transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) documentation and then come back here to ask any specific quesiton you have.

Answer (score 0):

Depending the redis client that you use:

1) Use Redis transactions and optimistic locking. See [Redis Transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

2) Or Lua scripting, which will be executed in Redis atomically. See [EVAL](https://redis.io/commands/eval)